# How to display 2 sets of data on the same axis of ASP.NET chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, charts

I want to display 2 sets of data on the same axis of a chart . On the X axis I would be displaying the UserID and on Y axis the Avg marks of all papers checked by the user. But i also want to display the number of booklets for which the avg has been derived for each user . How to go about it? I want the chart to look like this[image]

Where The numbers besides the avgs are the number of papers checked by particular user.

Till now I have this:

```
     private void Bindchart()
    {

        string msg = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Teacher_code, sum(Total_marks)/ count(*) as avgmarks , COUNT(*) as no_of_copies from " + connection.Database + "_transctn where sub_code='" + DropDown_Subjects.SelectedValue + "' and Teacher_code!='' group by Teacher_code", connection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            DataTable ChartData = ds.Tables[0];

            //storing total rows count to loop on each Record  
            string[] XPointMember = new string[ChartData.Rows.Count];


            decimal[] YPointMember = new decimal[ChartData.Rows.Count];

            int totalrows = ChartData.Rows.Count;

            if (totalrows > 0)
            {
                for (int count = 0; count < ChartData.Rows.Count; count++)
                {
                    //storing Values for X axis  
                    XPointMember[count] = ChartData.Rows[count]["Teacher_code"].ToString();
                    //storing values for Y Axis  
                    YPointMember[count] = Convert.ToDecimal(ChartData.Rows[count]["avgmarks"]);




                }
                //binding chart control  
                Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(XPointMember, YPointMember);

                //Setting width of line  
                Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 5;
                //setting Chart type   
                Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                //Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;  

                //Hide or show chart back GridLines  
                Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
                Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;

                //Enabled 3D  
                //Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;  
                connection.Close();
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your SQL here.", connection);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        DataTable ChartData = ds.Tables[0];

        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(ChartData.DefaultView, "Teacher_code", "avgmarks", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < Chart1.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
            Chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Label = string.Format("{0:0.00} ({1})", ChartData.Rows[i]["avgmarks"], ChartData.Rows[i]["no_of_copies"]);

        connection.Close();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: ..need help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078271/pie-chart-only-displaying-yvaluemembers

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it... but remember, I helped you with this question and you didn't bother to up vote my answer...;) Up voting helpful questions/answers is the right thing to do, please see it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Notice "someone" up voted this question of yours... guess who...:O)

Comment: sure :)..but i don't have enough reputations yet

Comment: Yes, you do...:O)

Comment: also need help with this please : [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028878/how-to-spread-columns-of-a-column-chart-obtained-from-a-result-set-of-a-stored-p