# ASP.NET Pie chart only displaying YValueMembers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, mschart

I am trying to create a chart to display the percentage of checked and unchecked answer booklets.But the pie chart is only showing the unchecked value which is the YValueMember. How to resolve this?

```
 protected void DropDown_Subjects_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart4.Visible = true;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select checked_percent, unchecked_percent From(select COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*)from[newexam2017].[dbo].[newexam2017] where sub_code = '" + DropDown_Subjects.SelectedValue + "') as checked_percent from[newexam2017].[dbo].[newexam2017]  where CheckBy is not null and sub_code = '" + DropDown_Subjects.SelectedValue + "' )checked,(select COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*)from[newexam2017].[dbo].[newexam2017] where sub_code = '" + DropDown_Subjects.SelectedValue + "')as unchecked_percent from[newexam2017].[dbo].[newexam2017]  where CheckBy is  null and sub_code = '" + DropDown_Subjects.SelectedValue + "')unchecked", connection);
    connection.Open();


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    DataTable ChartData = ds.Tables[0];
    Chart4.DataSource = ChartData;

    Chart4.Series[0].Points.DataBind(ChartData.DefaultView, "checked_percent", "unchecked_percent", "");

    for (int i = 0; i < Chart4.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
    Chart4.Series[0].Points[i].Label = string.Format("{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[i]["checked_percent"], "{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[i]["unchecked_percent"]);


    connection.Close();
   }
```

asp code:

```
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart4" runat="server"  BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" BackGradientStyle="LeftRight"  
        BorderlineWidth="0" Height="440px" Palette="SeaGreen" PaletteCustomColors="24, 0, 0"  
        Width="560px" BorderlineColor="128, 128, 255" OnLoad="Chart4_Load">

             <Titles>
            <asp:Title Name="DefaultTitle" Font="Trebuchet MS, 15pt, style=Bold"
                  Text = "Overall Scoring Progress" />
      </Titles>
    <%--  <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="DefaultLegend" Enabled="True" Docking="Top" />
      </Legends>--%>

            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1"  IsValueShownAsLabel="true"  YValuesPerPoint="10"  ChartType="Pie"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea4" >

</asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

What I want:

[image: chart1]

What I get :

[image: chart2]

Comment: Are you using Highcharts? If yes, then it looks like you are not using [Highcharts .NET](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/) and you could consider using it, because this is the Highcharts supported solution for integration with .NET environment.

Comment: A pie chart can only display one Y value per point and contain only one single series. Take a look [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456674.aspx);. Or perhaps you should specify better what final result you want. A picture is always helpful.

Comment: You can also create a custom label as I explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338288/how-to-display-2-sets-of-data-on-the-same-axis-of-asp-net-chart/42343528?noredirect=1#comment77429532_42343528). Just be careful to not create a "misleading" chart, given that in this case you're already working with percentages.

Comment: Please check the edit above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment before. In general, if you want to make sure a specific user sees it, you have to add _**@somespecificusername**_.

Comment: Thanks ,I did try that but the comment might not have committed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pie chart, both, `checked_percent` and `unchecked_percent`, must be Y-values. Like this:

```
 protected void Chart4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Chart4.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, (double)ChartData.Rows[0]["unchecked_percent"]));
    Chart4.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, (double)ChartData.Rows[0]["checked_percent"]));
 }
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Including custom labels:

[image]

```
protected void Chart4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(0, (double)ChartData.Rows[0]["unchecked_percent"]);
    dp.Label = string.Format("unchecked\n{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[0]["unchecked_percent"]);
    Chart4.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);

    dp = new DataPoint(1, (double)ChartData.Rows[0]["checked_percent"]);
    dp.Label = string.Format("checked\n{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[0]["checked_percent"]);
    Chart4.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
}
```

Comment: Also need to show the corresponding labels..i.e checked,unchecked

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.